# Combine the outputs from SubOrchestrator Function

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-durable-functions

I have a Durable Function which reads a list of AzureAD groups and gets users from each group. Here is the code:

Orchestrator:

```
        public async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var groups = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<AzureADGroup>>("GroupsReaderFunction"), null);
            if (groups != null && groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    var processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<List<AzureADUser>>("SubOrchestratorFunction", group });
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);                
            }
         }
```

SubOrchestrator:

```
        public async Task<List<AzureADUser>> RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {            
            var request = context.GetInput<AzureADGroup>();
            var users = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<AzureADUser>>("UsersReaderFunction", request.objectId);
            return users;
         }
```

I need to put all the users from all the groups to a list + remove duplicate users (if any - because some users may exist in multiple groups) and run some activity functions with all users as input. How would I do that? Please let me know.

Error on trying out the code from Answers:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suborchestrator should return `List<AzureADUser>`

```cs
        public async Task<List<AzureADUser>> RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {            
            var request = context.GetInput<Group>();
            var users = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<AzureADUser>>("UsersReaderFunction", request.objectId);
            return users;
         }
```

Then your orchestrator can receive the output and combine the lists with

```cs
        public async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var groups = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<AzureADGroup>>("GroupsReaderFunction"), null);
            if (groups != null && groups.Count > 0)
            {
                 var processingTasks = new List<Task<List<AzureADUser>>>();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    var processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<List<AzureADUser>>("SubOrchestratorFunction", group);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
                var users = new List<AzureADUser>();
                foreach (var task in processingTasks)
                {
                    users.AddRange(await task);
                }
            }
         }
```

Im not familiar with AzureADUser but if you have an id or email you can use that to get distinct users from the list.
e.g.

```cs
var distinctList = users.GroupBy(user => user.Id).Select(userGrp => userGrp.First()).ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the above error on adding the above code.

Comment: Did you change to context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync<List<AzureADUser>>("SubOrchestratorFunction", group); and  public async Task<List<AzureADUser>> RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)

Comment: Oh yes forgot var processingTasks = new List<Task>(); should be var processingTasks = new List<Task<List<AzureADUser>>>();

Comment: Could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68072117/azure-durable-function-read-users-from-graph-in-a-quicker-way. Thank you!

Comment: I see an argument null exception on this line on execution. Could you please help?  foreach (var task in processingTasks)
                {
                    users.AddRange(await task);
                }

Comment: The result of a task is null. Either check if null before adding or ensure your activity doesnt return null but instead empty list.

Comment: Is there a way I could remove await from this line "users.AddRange(await task);"