# Azure Durable Function - read users from Graph in a quicker way

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-durable-functions

I have an Azure Function with Premium Plan where users from multiple AzureAD groups are read and put to a queue. Currently, I'm looking into converting this function to Durable Function and use consumption plan. Here is my code:

Orchestrator:

```
        public async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var groups = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<AzureADGroup>>("GroupsReaderFunction"), null);
            if (groups != null && groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    var processTask = context.CallSubOrchestratorAsync("SubOrchestratorFunction", group);
                    processingTasks.Add(processTask);
                }
                await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);                
            }
         }
```

SubOrchestrator:

```
        public async Task RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {            
            var request = context.GetInput<Group>();
            var users = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<AzureADUser>>("UsersReaderFunction", request.objectId);
            return users;
         }
```

Here is the function that gets users from AzureAD group:

```
        public async Task<List<AzureADUser>> GetUsersInGroup(Guid objectId)
        {            
            IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage members;
            members = await GraphServiceClient.Groups[objectId.ToString()].TransitiveMembers.Request().Select("id").GetAsync();
            var toReturn = new List<AzureADUser>(ToUsers(members.CurrentPage));
            while (members.NextPageRequest != null)
            {
                    members = await members.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
                    toReturn.AddRange(ToUsers(members.CurrentPage));
            }               
            return toReturn;            
         }

        private IEnumerable<AzureADUser> ToUsers(IEnumerable<DirectoryObject> fromGraph)
        {
            foreach (var users in fromGraph)
            {
                return new AzureADUser { ObjectId = Guid.Parse(user.Id) };
            }
        }
```

Number of users in groups vary - one group contains 10 users and another group contains ~500k users. Timeout occurs when reading users from larger groups (> 10 minutes). Is there a faster way to get users from AzureAD group (for example, get users in batches) so that I should be able to use Consumption Plan? Or is there a different way to use Durable Functions (fan in - fan out pattern or some other patterns) for a faster performance?

UPDATE:

```
        var users = new List<AzureADUser>();

        public async Task RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {            
            var request = context.GetInput<Group>();
            var response = await context.CallActivityAsync<(List<AzureADUser> users, nextPageLink link)>("UsersReaderFunction", request.objectId);
            users.AddRange(response.users);
            return users;
         }
```

Here response contains 2 values - users from current page and link to next page. I need to keep calling "UsersReaderFunction" activity function until link to next page is null.

```
        var users = new List<AzureADUser>();

        public async Task RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {            
            var request = context.GetInput<Group>();
            var response = await context.CallActivityAsync<(List<AzureADUser> users, nextPageLink link)>("UsersReaderFunction", request.objectId);
            users.AddRange(response.users);
            while (response.link != null) {
                var response = await context.CallActivityAsync<(List<AzureADUser> users, nextPageLink link)>("UsersReaderFunction", request.objectId);
                users.AddRange(response.users);
            }
            return users;
         }
```

But this is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Im not that familiar with the graphservice client or ms graph api. But how many members are returned per page? There should probably be a count params to get X users per page.

Comment: Let me check that. If I can get  the count per page, what could be updated? Please let me know.

Comment: Based on this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging, users in a page are returned as result. If the result contains a link to the next page, users exist in the next page and it goes on until the link is null. Is it possible to call activity function, return users in a page along with next page link. Until next page link is null, call activity function. In that way, timeout may not occur? Please let me know.

Comment: @Bjorne Please check UPDATE section and let me know your thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: @user989988 Did you ever get this to work?